# Не наследуется шаблон twig

Tags: php, symfony, twig, шаблонизаторы

symfony 4, twig 4.2

Имеется базовый шаблон base.html.twig:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="sidebar">
            {% block sidebar %}
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/">Заявки</a></li>
                <li><a href="/D#">Достопримечательности</a></li>
                <li><a href="/D#">Маршруты</a></li>
                <li><a href="/D#">Контакты</a></li>
            </ul>
            {% endblock %}
        </div>

        <div id="content">
            {% block content %}
            {% endblock %}
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Имеется дочерний шаблон request.html.twig:

```
{% extends "base.html.twig" %}

{% block title %} Заявки {% endblock %}

{% block sidebar %}
    {{ parent() }}
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    {{ parent() }}
{% endblock %}
```

Вызываю php-скрипт:

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class AdminController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/admin")
     */
    public function admin()
    {
        return $this->render('admin/request.html.twig');
    }
}
```

Из блоков меняется только title.

Если возвращаю return $this->render('admin/base.html.twig'); - то все выводится.

P.s. Дело точно не в зависимостях.

Заранее извиняюсь если такой вопрос уже задавали - не нашел.

Comment: А что еще должно измениться?

Comment: должно при выводе request.html.twig выводится тоже самое что и при base.html.twig

Comment: Как вы поняли, что не наследуется?

Comment: При вызове он должен был вывести {% block sidebar %} определенный в родительском шаблоне

Answer (score 0, accepted):

проблема заключалась в том что в extends было написано "base.html.twig". Данный шаблон был написано мною и находился в папке admin/, где и находится request.html.twig. Шаблон с точно таким же названием находился директорией выше, и extends, написанный в request.html.twig наследовал шаблон не в текущей директории (admin/), а директорией выше.

P.s. при переходе (go to declaration) из {% extends "admin/base.html.twig"} phpstorm перенаправлял на нужный файл.